# Ubuntu 20.04 black screen on booting. My laptop is HP

Tags: boot, dual-boot, screen, hp

My laptop is hp and I'm a new user of linux OS. I have dual OS (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04) for approximately 2 months now (so it's not a fresh installation problem).

Everything was ok except for a system error that popped up when I was in ubuntu the last days, informing me about a space problem. I ignored the problem (i don't know if this was such a big mistake). At some point, I wanted to download a pdf file of a very small size and it didn't let me, even if I deleted stuff from the pc. So, I turned to windows in order to be able to download the file and watch it. After that, I tried booting ubuntu again and it didn't let me in, as a black screen appeared. This is happening the last 3 days every time I try to boot ubuntu.

I searched similar topics and I tried all solutions I found using the BIOS (like booting from another ubuntu option from the advanced settings, adding orders at the line which starts with word "linux" after pressing the key E on the ubuntu option..), however nothing worked.
I read that reinstalling ubuntu might solve the issue, but I would rather another solution, if there is any other, because I am not familiar with installing OS, let alone dual OS. Apart from that, I haven't used ubuntu for such a long time to make something so wrong and I wouldn't like to reinstall ubuntu every time I face an issue...

Thank you all in advance..

Comment: after pressing e in grub menu, add nomodeset before quite splash and see if it works ...

Comment: @kannzzmm2 I tried it and then pressed Ctrl+X but again it opened a black screen. It writes " [    74.852621] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0:  HSW/BDW HD-audio HDMI/DP requires binding with gs driver "

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=232461 give it a try

Comment: @kannzzmm2 thank you very much again for the reply. I went to BIOS but I didn't see anything named "nvidia" or mentioning "audio driver". I googled it but I didn't find an answer on how to find my audio drivers in BIOS...   I am a new user and maybe I have gaps in knowledge and that makes it more difficult. I'm sorry for that. Any other help on how to find the audio drivers? I have hp..

Comment: in Bios there is nothing about Nvidia or audio driver.. See the suggested link from the first comment, and try to add in grub config nomodeset